# How integrate activiti explorer with spring

Tags: java, spring, activiti, bpmn

I use activiti in my project. when i run project it crate all activiti tables in my (mysql) database. I want use embed H2 of activiti database. Now my question is how integrate activiti with spring that when i process a task all information save in embed database?

Comment: it is really hard to answer a question like this, can you please try it out and ask a more specific question

Answer (score 2):

add this in you applicationContext.xml file

```
<!-- Activiti Configuration -->
    <bean id="processEngine" class="org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean">
        <property name="processEngineConfiguration" ref="processEngineConfiguration" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceActiviti" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="ActivitiTransactionManager" />
        <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" />
        <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="true" />
        <!-- <property name="deploymentResources" value="classpath*:diagrams/*.bpmn20.xml" 
            /> -->
        <!-- <property name="deploymentResources" value="classpath*:/diagrams/*.bpmn" 
            /> -->
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSourceActiviti"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:activiti;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=1000" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="ActivitiTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceActiviti" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="repositoryService" factory-bean="processEngine"
        factory-method="getRepositoryService" />
    <bean id="runtimeService" factory-bean="processEngine"
        factory-method="getRuntimeService" />
    <bean id="taskService" factory-bean="processEngine"
        factory-method="getTaskService" />
    <bean id="historyService" factory-bean="processEngine"
        factory-method="getHistoryService" />
    <bean id="managementService" factory-bean="processEngine"
        factory-method="getManagementService" />
    <bean id="formService" factory-bean="processEngine"
        factory-method="getFormService" />
    <bean id="identityService" factory-bean="processEngine"
        factory-method="getIdentityService" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Study Activiti's documentation which is quite good ([link](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/index.html#_getting_started_10_minute_tutorial)).
I'm sharing a [link](http://programmingoverflow14.blogspot.in/2016/01/jump-start-with-activiti-bpm-along-with.html) of example in which activiti is used in spring mvc project.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you can refer to the activiti http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#databaseConfiguration part